# How do I Access BIOS with no OS?

Tags: boot, bios

I'm not sure how much information you'll need, so here's a short version first: Acer Spin 1 (SP111-32N-C2X3). There's no OS on my PC, and when I power on I see the black grub> page. If I hit F2 while I power up, the grub> page still appears, but I can type "exit" and hit enter, and it will take me to a "BOOT MANAGER" page. Those are the only two screens I have figured out how to access. How do I access BIOS?

Some background may be necessary to answer this: I have an Acer Spin 1 (SP111-32N-C2X3). It came with Windows 10, but the updates quickly filled the SSD, and I don't like Windows anyway, so I decided to completely replace Windows with Ubuntu from a bootable USB.

That's where I encountered my first problem: I chose the installation method that wipes the disk and replaces it with Ubuntu, but the install would hang at the grub installation. After some research, I found out that Acer laptops don't play well with Ubuntu, specifically the grub.

So I used the command ubiquity -b to install Ubuntu without the grub, thinking I could install it afterwards in a less direct way. When trying grub-install, I got an error saying it couldn't find '/cow'. Long story short, none of the suggestions for resolving that problem worked, so I decided to just shut the computer down, unplug the USB, and play with some BIOS settings.

When I booted back up (while pressing the F2 BIOS key) the grub> page appeared instead of the BIOS. After a while I realized I could type "exit," and it would take me to a BIOS-looking page, except all it lets me change is boot order! It says "BOOT MANAGER" at the top.

Finally, my question: How do I get into BIOS when my only ways of interfacing with the computer are the grub> menu, the keyboard, and this BOOT MANAGER (which only allows me to press the up arrow, down arrow, and "enter" to choose different boot media)?

Edit: According to the manual F2 is the correct key, which I've been pressing as fast as humanly possible as soon as I hit the power button.

Comment: BIOS and boot loader are separate things. BIOS happens first, then boot loader. BIOS has nothing to do with Linux.

Comment: Perhaps you just weren't fast enough in pressing F2? If you're used to traditional BIOS, systems with UEFI firmware can sometimes surprise you in how short the "press F2 to enter system settings" time window can be.

Comment: And sometimes you need a different key than F2 (depending on the BIOS/UEFI manufacturer). The ones I try are ESC, F2, F10, F12 and DEL. Usually one of them gets you into the BIOS/UEFI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Reinstall Windows, this should overwrite anything that you've broken and at least make the device usable (use the creating Installation media heading):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

2. Use your Linux bootable USB to startup attempt to correctly install GRUB/some alternative.

Answer (score 0):

How to access the BIOS depends on your laptop model, you should check its manual.

GRUB is the boot loader and is loaded just after the BIOS.  It is independent from it.

You should access the BIOS, disable Secure Boot, and set the option to boot from USB (if it isn't set already).  Then reinstall Ubuntu - or any other distro, e.g. [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Acer/Spin1) - from a USB drive. This should fix the GRUB problem and end up with a working computer.

Comment: According to the computer's manual, F2 is the right key, and I start pressing it as fast as humanly possible as soon as I hit the power button.

Comment: Hold the F2 key down, don't press it fast.